# I am trying to deploy a simple react and nodejs application using heroku but after deployment it is just showing hello world, unable to figure it out?

Tags: node.js, express

According to online tutorials i ran npm run build in the react app and then pasted the build folder in the server directory but i think it is just serving the server side, i am unable to figure out the problem , please help me what is the error in its deployment

**My index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path")

const { MONGODB } = require("./config");
const model = require("./models/user");
const router = require("./Routes/auth");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

/***********************************config ************************* */
mongoose.connect(MONGODB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("connected to mongoDb");
});

/********************model imports ***************************/

const User = require("./models/user");
const Post = require("./models/post");

/********************************middlewares**************************** */
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(router);
app.use(require("./Routes/posts"));
app.use(require("./Routes/user"));


/****code related to production of app***** */

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));


app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


/**********************listening on server *********************** */
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  }
  console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

**my package.json - server**

```
{
  "name": "instagram-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

Github link: https://github.com/dhruv354/insta-app.git

Comment: does it run locally?

Comment: Individually i had run both React and express apps and they are running fine and also able to connect with  each other

Comment: ok cool, now try to build the frontend and put it in the backend static folder, and give it a try locally

Comment: I tried but is just listening to backend

Comment: I tried to ran npm start but and is just listening to backend, according to online tutorial that   I watched my app should run  at port 3000

Comment: if you haven't set the `PORT` env var, it should be running in `8000`.

Comment: Yes it is running on port 8000 and there is no effect of adding build folder , it is running as like only a nodejs app

Comment: There are some synatactical errors and i have'nt created handler for / route thats why it is not working for that endpoint , it is working fine now